# The cv2.imshow not showing webcam video and not opening any window

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, face-recognition, webcam-capture

I have an issue with showing up the window and cam capture using OpenCV

When i'm run the script, i see that the cam is working, but the window with this cam is not showing anywhere, i've had just the Python icon showed up but it`s even not clickable.

[image: here]

setup:

- macOS Big Sur 11.4
- python 3.8
- cv2 4.2.0

I`ve tried to:

- Add sleep before `ret, frame = video_capture.read()`
- Change cv2.waitKey() to 0, 1, and 500
- Had tested on my notebook cam, and on phone using IriunWebcam
- Tried different IDEs(Visual code, and PyCharm), and tried to run the
  script in the terminal

```
import cv2
import sys
import logging as log
import datetime as dt
from time import sleep

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/***/Documents/GitHub/FaceAuth/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
log.basicConfig(filename='webcam.log', level=log.INFO)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # 0 for phone cam, 1 for pc cam
anterior = 0

while True:
    if not video_capture.isOpened():
        print('Unable to load camera.')
        sleep(5)
        pass

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    if anterior != len(faces):
        anterior = len(faces)
        log.info("faces: " + str(len(faces)) + " at " + str(dt.datetime.now()))

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: here] This is my variables in debug breakpoint, before `cv2.imshow('Video', frame)`

Comment: Have you tried upgrading opencv to 4.4.0?
Maybe it should work, 4.4.0 is the latest version.

Comment: Try changing `faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/***/Documents/GitHub/FaceAuth/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')` to `faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")`.

Comment: What is the 2nd cv2.imshow('Video', frame) supposed to do? it might be slowing stuff down unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @idonthaveaname in the comments section:

> Have you tried upgrading opencv to 4.4.0? Maybe it should work, 4.4.0 is the latest version.